# How to make a Custom UIButton to toggle a Sound On/Off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, toggle

i am an n00b and seeking help.

Now i can start a Soundfile with Following code:

```
- (void)addButtonSpeaker {
UIButton *buttonSpeaker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
                            [buttonSpeaker setFrame:CGRectMake(650, 930, 63, 66)];
[buttonSpeaker setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonLesen.png"] 
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonSpeaker addTarget:self action:@selector(playAudio)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:buttonSpeaker];
 }

- (void)playAudio {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Vorwort" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    
 fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
self.audioPlayer = theAudio;
[theAudio release];
[theAudio play];
 }
```

With the same Button i would like to stop and play the sound.
Maybe i am searching for the wrong thing, but i can´t find the proper information on the web.

It would be really helpful if someone could give me a LINK to a tutorial or something like this.

thanks in advance
Planky

Comment: You could rename the `playAudio` method in `toggleAudio`, and handle toggling playing sound there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the *AVAudioPlayer* player object on *loadView* or somewhere.

```
- (void)loadView {

    // Some code here
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Vorwort" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    self.audioPlayer = theAudio;
    [theAudio release];
    // Some code here
}
```

Then inside the button's action(change the action name to *toggleAudio* as others suggested), you can get the property **isPlaying** to see whether audio is playing or not, and do the respective actions.

```
- (void)toggleAudio { // original name is playAudio

    if ([self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {

        [self.audioPlayer pause]; 
        // Or, [self.audioPlayer stop];

    } else {

        [self.audioPlayer play];
    }
}
```

Comment: You made my day! Thanks from Austria.

Comment: Welcome. Cheers from India! ;-)